# A countable elementary submodel of $L_{\omega_1}$

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

Let $N \prec \left(L_{\omega_1}, \in\right)$ be a countable elementary submodel.

In Jech Set Theory he states:

> $N$ is transitive. Let $X\in N$. Let $f$ be the $<$-least mapping of $\omega$ onto $X$. Since $f$ is definable in $(L_{\omega_1}, \in)$ from $X$, $f$ is in $N$. Hence $f(n)\in N$ for all $n<\omega$ and we get $X\subset N$.

What I don't understand is the way $f$ is chosen and the reasoning behind why it is definable and how.

Can you apply the above to an elementary submodel $N\prec L_{\omega_2}$ s.t $|N|=\aleph_0$?

Comment: $N$ is an elementary submodel of $L_{\omega_1}$, so it satisfies $V=L$, which means $N$ has a definable global well-order. Thus we can choose $f$ by employing this global well-order, and such the least $f$ is definable.

Comment: The point is that we can characterize a property of $f$, and the definable global well-order makes choosing the least such $f$ possible, and everything we did is expressible by a first-order sentence. It implies the definability of $f$.

Comment: Is the fact that $N$ is countable used anywhere?

Comment: Never mind I see that it is used in $L_{\omega_1} \models V = L $

Comment: Well but it is just an artifact of $\omega_1$ isn't it? I mean if we were looking on $L_{\kappa^+}$ your argument still holds

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment (that was deleted) was wrong. I guess you are attempting to prove Exercise 13.17 of Jech.

Comment: Yes. From it I hope to deduce somthing else (the second question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main points of the argument is that every object in $L_{\omega_1}$ is countable *internally*. (Of course, $\omega_1=\omega_1^L$ in this problem.) That is, $L_{\omega_1}$ catches every set in itself is countable. Since $N\prec L_{\omega_1}$, $N$ also thinks every object is countable.

Thus this argument does not work if we replace $\omega_1$ with other ordinals, like $\omega_2$: every countable elementary submodel of $L_{\omega_2}$ would think there is an uncountable set, although it could not be a genuine uncountable set.

I explained why $f$ is definable in the comment, but let me summarize the point: $L_{\omega_1}$ thinks there is a *definable* global well-order (namely $<_L$.) Thus $N$ also thinks there is a global well-order which is definable. Hence the formula

$$\phi(f) :\equiv [f\text{ is onto from $\omega$ to $X$ and $f$ is the $<_L$-least function among them}]$$
is a first-order formula which defines an object (which is a function we desire.)

Comment: So the following statement is true: $N_1, N_2 \prec L_{\omega_2}$ both countable and $N_1 \in N_2$ then $N_1 \subset N_2$ right?

Comment: Or for each set $L_{\omega_2}$ thinks is countable and $N_2$ thinks it is countable as well (via the your argument).

Comment: @ItamarShmelo I cannot see the motivation of your first statement, and I have no idea about it. For the second statement, yes, if $X\in N_2\prec L_{\omega_2}$ and $L_{\omega_2}$ thinks $X$ is countable, then so is $N_2$.

Comment: (Unfortunately, I am going to sleep for the exam supervision scheduled today, so any answer to the subsequent questions will be delayed.)